# start-mapred.sh file not present in Hadoop 2.7.0

Tags: 14.04, hadoop

I have installed Hadoop 2.7.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. `start-dfs.sh`,`start-yarn.sh` and `start-all.sh` files are in the **sbin** directory. But `start-mapred.sh` is not present in the directory. what might be the problem in my installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a problem with your installation. Hadoop 2 uses **YARN** framework i.e. MapReduce 2.0 (MRv2).
Refer [Hadoop Yarn](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) for more details.

So, `start-mapred.sh` is not required. To start Hadoop, use `start-all.sh` or `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`.

YARN’s original purpose was to split up the two major responsibilities of the JobTracker/TaskTracker into separate entities:

- a global ResourceManager
- a per-application ApplicationMaster
- a per-node slave NodeManager
- a per-application Container running on a NodeManager

You might be following tutorials explaining Hadoop 1 setup.

[Apache Hadoop Yarn](http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Apache.Hadoop.YARN_.Sample.pdf) will help you.

Comment: Glad I could help!